# How to make dependable dropdown with jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I pre-populated select tag tags with option values coming from PHP variables, and the HTML looks like this:

```
 <!-- Type -->
 <select id="d1">
    <option type="colours" value="Colours">Colours</option>
    <option type="fruit" value="Fruit">Fruit</option>
 </select>
 <!-- Group -->
 <select id="d2">
    <option type="colours_dark" subtype="dark" value="Dark">Dark</option>
    <option type="colours_light" subtype="light" value="Light">Light</option>
    <option type="fruit_ripe" value="Ripe">Ripe</option>
    <option type="fruit_rotten" value="Rotten">Rotten</option>
 </select>
 <!-- Items -->
 <select id="d3" style="display: none;">
    <option value="">Choose a color</option>
    <option type="colours_dark" value="Black">Black</option>
    <option type="colours_dark" value="Brown">Brown</option>
    <option type="colours_dark" value="Grey">Grey</option>
    <option type="colours_light" value="Red">Red</option>
    <option type="colours_light" value="Green">Green</option>
    <option type="colours_light" value="Blue">Blue</option>
    <option type="fruit_ripe" value="Banana">Banana</option>
    <option type="fruit_ripe" value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option type="fruit_ripe" value="Orange">Orange</option>
    <option type="fruit_rotten" value="Pear">Pear</option>
    <option type="fruit_rotten" value="Peach">Peach</option>
    <option type="fruit_rotten" value="Mango">Mango</option>
 </select>
```

Initially, I don't want the third dropdown to show because the values will depend on the second dropdown, so I added the following to my jQuery snippet:

```
var dropDown1Selected = dropDown1.find('option').filter(':selected').val();
if(dropDown3.find('option').filter(':selected').val() == '') {
   dropDown3.hide();
}
```

Based on my HTML, how do I make the options of dropdown 2 show depending on dropdown 1, and then have dropdown 3 showing depending on dropdown 3?

Eg: If  I select fruit from dropdown 1, dropdown 2 should only show Ripe, and Rotten. And if I choose Ripe, then dropdown 3 should only show Apple and Orange.

I tried the following in my jQuery snippet, but am struggling to change the dropdown options:

```
$('#d1').on('change', function(e) {
    var val = this.value;
    
    // check if val exists in d2 options
    $("#d2 option").filter(function() {
        
    });
    
}).change();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this work for you, I make dropdown 3 filtered with dropdown 2 so you don't need to hide it

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {
            filterOption("d1", "d2");
            filterOption("d2", "d3");
        })
        $('#d1').on('change', function (e) {
            filterOption("d1", "d2");
            filterOption("d2", "d3");
        })
        $('#d2').on('change', function (e) {
            filterOption("d2", "d3");
        })

        function filterOption(parent, child) {
            var parent = $(`#${parent} :selected`).attr('type');
            $(`#${child} option`).each(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == "" || $(this).attr('type').includes(parent)) {
                    $(this).show();
                }
                else {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            })
            $(`#${child}`).val($(`#${child} option:visible:first`).val());
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Type -->
    <select id="d1">
        <option type="colours" value="Colours">Colours</option>
        <option type="fruit" value="Fruit">Fruit</option>
    </select>
    <!-- Group -->
    <select id="d2">
        <option type="colours_dark" subtype="dark" value="Dark">Dark</option>
        <option type="colours_light" subtype="light" value="Light">Light</option>
        <option type="fruit_ripe" value="Ripe">Ripe</option>
        <option type="fruit_rotten" value="Rotten">Rotten</option>
    </select>
    <!-- Items -->
    <select id="d3">
        <option value="">Choose a color</option>
        <option type="colours_dark" value="Black">Black</option>
        <option type="colours_dark" value="Brown">Brown</option>
        <option type="colours_dark" value="Grey">Grey</option>
        <option type="colours_light" value="Red">Red</option>
        <option type="colours_light" value="Green">Green</option>
        <option type="colours_light" value="Blue">Blue</option>
        <option type="fruit_ripe" value="Banana">Banana</option>
        <option type="fruit_ripe" value="Apple">Apple</option>
        <option type="fruit_ripe" value="Orange">Orange</option>
        <option type="fruit_rotten" value="Pear">Pear</option>
        <option type="fruit_rotten" value="Peach">Peach</option>
        <option type="fruit_rotten" value="Mango">Mango</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Ideally, each dropdown should only be visible depending on what is clicked on the first dropdown. However, I still marked the answer as favourite because it definitely points into the right direction.